# How to create a bookmark for an audiobook on the iPhone?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I'm listening to an audio book in the Music app on the iPhone.  When I switch to listen to something else, say Apple Music, then I lose my place in my audio book.  How can I bookmark my place?

Comment: iTunes on the iPhone is just the store. Depending on the way your audiobook is encoded you probably are listening to it in either Music or iBooks. Which app is it?

Comment: @patrix - Its listed under "My Music" in the "Music" app.